# Yii2 Dynamic Form Error on Create - The 'model' property must be set and must extend from '\yii\base\Model'

Tags: php, yii2, dynamic-forms

In Yii2, I have been trying to create a dynamic form using the below tutorials.
[Yii2-dynamicForm - GitHub](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform) and [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAg0LIrZDdk).

I followed the same step as mentioned in tutorials, unfortunately I am held up with an error(screenshot attached)[image: Error Screen]

And I am not able to resolve this error, can any one help me to find what I am missing.

For the reference I am attaching my Models here, rest the controllers and views are same as the tutorials.

**Request Model**

```
   <?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
class Request extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'request';
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['req_date', 'req_on', 'req_updated_on'], 'safe'],
            [['req_job', 'req_type', 'material_type', 'req_status'], 'required'],
            [['req_by'], 'integer'],
            [['req_status'], 'string'],
            [['req_job', 'req_type'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['material_type'], 'string', 'max' => 150],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'req_id' => 'Req ID',
            'req_date' => 'Req Date',
            'req_job' => 'Job No',
            'req_type' => 'Type of Request',
            'req_on' => 'Required On',
            'material_type' => 'Material Type',
            'req_by' => 'Req By',
            'req_updated_on' => 'Req Updated On',
            'req_status' => 'Request Status',
        ];
    }
}
```

**RequestItems Model**

```
    <?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "request_items".
 *
 * @property int $req_item_id
 * @property int $req_id
 * @property string $item_name
 * @property string $item_qty
 * @property string $item_unit
 */
class RequestItems extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'request_items';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['req_id', 'item_name', 'item_qty', 'item_unit'], 'required'],
            [['req_id'], 'integer'],
            [['item_name'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['item_qty', 'item_unit'], 'string', 'max' => 25],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'req_item_id' => 'Req Item ID',
            'req_id' => 'Req ID',
            'item_name' => 'Item Name',
            'item_qty' => 'Item Qty',
            'item_unit' => 'Item Unit',
        ];
    }
}
```

**_form.php**

```
    <?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use kartik\checkbox\CheckboxX;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Request */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="request-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form']); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'req_date')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php
                $data = ['1001' => '1001/Sample Job 1', '1002' => '1002/Sample Job 2', '1003' => '1003/Sample Job 3']; 
                echo $form->field($model, 'req_job')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                'data' => $data,
                'class'=>'form-control',
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'req_type')->radioList(array('Urgent'=>'Urgent','Normal'=>'Normal'));  ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'req_on')->input('date') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'material_type')->radioList(array('Civil'=>'Civil','Mechanical'=>'Mechanical', 'Manpower'=>'Manpower')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'req_by')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'req_updated_on')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
        </div>
    </div>


<!-- code for dynamic form -->
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Request Items</h4></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
             <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                'limit' => 4, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                'model' => $modelsAddress,
                'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                'formFields' => [
                    'item_name',
                    'item_qty',
                    'item_unit',
                ],
            ]); ?>

            <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
            <?php foreach ($modelsAddress as $i => $modelAddress): ?>
                <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Requested Items</h3>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <?php
                            // necessary for update action.
                            if (! $modelAddress->isNewRecord) {
                                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelAddress, "[{$i}]id");
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?= $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]item_name")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]item_qty")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]item_unit")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- .row -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>






    <?= $form->field($requestModel, 'req_status')->dropDownList(['Requested' => 'Requested', 'Approved' => 'Approved', 'Rejected' => 'Rejected', 'Hold' => 'Hold',], ['prompt' => '']) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: you are probably missing the `model` property in the `DynamicFormWidget::begin()` method you should define one accordingly , add your view

Comment: @mohammed Omer Aslam I updated the question with the _form.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the

```
'model'=>$modelsAddress
```

to

```
'model'=>$modelsAddress[0]
```

As stated in the basic example, its an array of models and the way you passing, it will be detected as array rather than a model.